# Error encountered when accessing Spreadsheet via getActiveSheet() -- works correctly any other way

Tags: google-apps-script

I've been working up a set of scripts in Google Apps Script (specifically on a set of spreadsheets) for over a month now, and all of a sudden I am getting errors any time I try to access a sheet via `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()`.

I assumed I threw something off in one of my functions somewhere, until I wrote up a test function that didn't rely on any of my own code:

```
function basicFunctionality() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange('b2');
  var vals = range.getValues();
  Browser.msgBox(vals[0][0]);
}
```

Running this function returns this error...

```
Unknown sheet name (line 5)
```

...which would seem to imply an issue with the "getValues" line, except that when I access the sheet by any means other than `getActiveSpreadsheet()` (e.g. `getSheetByName()`, `getSheets()[0]`), the function runs to the end and returns the expected result.

Now, I'm still assuming this is an issue in my code files, and not a Google bug -- but I've run out of ideas. I have even tried copying all my script files to a new spreadsheet document/project -- this test function works if it's the only thing I port over, but once the rest of the project gets in there, the issue crops up again (even if I comment every other file out entirely, which is the most bizarre part).

Is there any way I could have conceivably "broken" `getActiveSheet()`? Or am I misidentifying the problem?

Thanks in advance for any insights!

Comment: Are you still getting this error?  Because I was observing exactly the same thing yesterday my time (approx 18 hours ago) - `getActiveSheet()` worked OK when in a solitary function but was broken when in a function amongst other code.  But now it seems to work again for me.

Comment: I'm still seeing the issue on my end. It started for me yesterday Pacific Time, as well. It's been about 22 hours now, in total.

Comment: Please ensure you have authorized the script. Also, try removing commented code until it works again. Perhaps you can isolate the particular code that is causing the problem.

Comment: Sorry for the extended silence -- Just FYI, the issue "resolved itself" about 48 hours later, without needing to modify any code on my end. After that point, I neglected to come back here and report the good news...thanks for all your input!

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine for me. I attached the function to a drawing I dropped into a spreadsheet, ran it, and it returned the data from cell B2 in that sheet.

Could you try it again to check that it's still broken for you?

Is it possible that the script is running in some context where GAS doesn't know what the active sheet is? When I ran the code in the debugger it seemed to pick the first sheet as the active sheet regardless of which sheet had last had input.